# How to run (not ignore) runnableExamples in nim

Tags: nim-lang

In nim, how do you get [runnableExamples](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#runnableExamples%2Cstring%2Cuntyped) to be run instead of ignored? That documentation reveals:

> In normal debug and release builds code within a runnableExamples section
> is ignored.

A normal debug or release build as opposed to what? How do you get it to not be ignored? Is the next line intended to be the answer to that question, to not ignore it you have to do something with the documentation generator?

Here is some example code, from the documentation:

```
proc timesTwo*(x: int): int =
  ## This proc doubles a number.
  runnableExamples:
    # at module scope
    const exported* = 123
    assert timesTwo(5) == 10
    block: # at block scope
      defer: echo "done"
  runnableExamples "-d:foo -b:cpp":
    import std/compilesettings
    assert querySetting(backend) == "cpp"
    assert defined(foo)
  runnableExamples "-r:off": ## this one is only compiled
     import std/browsers
     openDefaultBrowser "https://forum.nim-lang.org/"
  2 * x
```

Comment: I could not find the information in the manual either.

Answer (score 4):

The examples get ran during doc generation e.g. `nim doc foo.nim`